# Multiple curl commands in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have the following code with 3 curl commands in a shell script test.sh.

```
curl -o C:\Users\user1\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\25Oct2021.gz "https://abc.xyz.aaa.com/v3/test-logs/download?userID=AA4d3DFF&fileName=25Oct2021.gz" --header "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
curl -o C:\Users\user1\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\24Oct2021.gz "https://abc.xyz.aaa.com/v3/test-logs/download?userID=AA4d3DFF&fileName=24Oct2021.gz" --header "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
curl -o C:\Users\user1\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\23Oct2021.gz "https://abc.xyz.aaa.com/v3/test-logs/download?userID=AA4d3DFF&fileName=23Oct2021.gz" --header "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

I am using a Windows 10 machine and when I try to execute the shell script at command prompt using `sh test.sh`, the files don't download as expected. If I take the individual curl commands and execute them at command prompt, they work perfectly fine.
I tried tweaking the shell script and removing "\r" and running this. Are there any additional things that I can try to make this work?

I edited the Shell script to run just one of the curl commands as well and here are the results.

This is the output with running the shell script as `sh test.sh`

```
>sh test1.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    29    0    29    0     0     29      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    56
```

This is the output of one of the individual curl commands:

```
curl -o C:\Users\user1\folder1\folder2\folder4\folder4\25Oct2021.gz "https://abc.xyz.aaa.com/v3/test-logs/download?userID=AA4d3DFF&fileName=25Oct2021.gz" --header "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 4035k    0 4035k    0     0   672k      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--  838k
```

Update:
Running with curl -v gives me the below output for one curl command within the script test.sh

```
sh test1.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 11.111.111.111...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to abc.xyz.aaa (11.111.111.111) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with abc.xyz.aaa port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: checking server certificate revocation
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 184 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 184 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with abc.xyz.aaa port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with abc.xyz.aaa port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 3026
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 3026 length 4096
* schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 93 bytes...
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with abc.xyz.aaa port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 258
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 258 length 4096
* schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with abc.xyz.aaa port 443 (step 3/3)
* schannel: stored credential handle in session cache
> GET /v3/test-logs/download?UserId=AA4d3DFF&fileName=25Oct2021.gz HTTP/1.1
> Host: abc.xyz.aaa
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 103424
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: encrypted data got 303
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 303 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 274
* schannel: decrypted data added: 274
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 274 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 274 length 102400
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 274
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 102400
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Server: acvf
< Date: Mon, 25 Oct 2021 18:53:02 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
< pragma: no-cache
< expires: -1
<
{ [40 bytes data]
100    29    0    29    0     0     29      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    50
* Connection #0 to host abc.xyz.aaa left intact
```

Comment: The script completes successfully without any downloads

Comment: The output from the script shows only one `curl` command running, not three. Maybe putting some `echo` commands in between will help you find out what's going on.

Comment: I removed the 2 of 3 curl commands in a test to run just one curl command as a part of the script

Comment: The download size of the script doesn't match that of the manual run. Try adding `-v` to make curl more verbose so you can see what it's connecting to (`Connecting to xxx` line) and what path it's requesting (`GET xxx HTTP/1.1` line) and update your post with the full output (redacted if needed).

Comment: Just as a test, try to remove the directory `C:\Users\user1\folder1\folder2\folder4\folder4\` and run your script of three commands. If still not working, put " #" (a space and hash sign, no quotes) at the end of each line. Are you using git-bash package ?

Comment: Added the verbose output to the post

Comment: In your command window, run this command  `dir /od` Do you see three files with long name and small size ?

Comment: @Philippe - yes I do

Comment: Can you paste the content of of those files ?

Comment: It says ```{"reason":"Bad credentials."}```

Comment: That's why I asked *put " #" (a space and hash sign, no quotes) at the end of each line.*

Comment: @Philippe - I added the " #" at the end of the line and tried it. I still get the same error

Comment: Figured it out! The Authorization code had some special characters and I needed to escape them and it worked!

Comment: What special characters can a Bearer string have ? As you used double quotes, it should be fine.

Comment: It had a "$" and escaping it made it work

Comment: In that case, you can use single quotes, then you don't need escaping.

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an escape character in (ba)sh, but not in the Windows command prompt, which explains the difference in execution.

You need to either double the backslashes (`\\`), enclose each string containing backslashes inside single quotes (`'`), or replace all backslashes by forward slashes (`/`).

Comment: I tried these --- double the backslashes ```(\\)```, replace all backslashes by forward slashes ```(/)``` but, it still doesn't work

Comment: Then please update your question to show the full output of the script. `curl` is not silent by default.

Comment: Output of the 2 executions updated